# Error: Error: Cannot find module ' in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, protractor

I try to make simple app ..try to test using protractor ? I install every thing  .and able to run protractor given example ..than I make my own example like this

**Index.html ..**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Super</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app ="app">
<div ui-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('app',['ui.router']).config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/state1");
    //
    // Now set up the states
    $stateProvider
        .state('state1', {
            url: "/state1",
            templateUrl: "partial/state1.html"    ,
            controller:function($scope){
                $scope.clikme=function(){
                    $scope.message="hello"
                }

            }
        })
})
```

**example.spec.js**

```
    var indexFunction=require('/indexFunction');





describe('angularjs homepage', function() {
    var page =new indexFunction();
    beforeEach(function(){
        page.getUrl()
    })
  it('should greet the named user', function() {
      expect(page.getTitile()).toEqual('Super');

  });

    it('should update',function(){

        page.clickMethod();
        expect(page.getMessage()).toBe('hello')
    })
});
```

**index.spec.js**

```
function indexFunction(){
    this.button= element(by.id('clickme'))  ;
    this.message=element(by.binding('message'))  ;

    this.getUrl=function(){
        browser.get('http://localhost:63342/example/index.html');

    }

    this.getTitile=function(){
        return browser.getTitle();
    }

    this.getMessage=function(){
        return this.message.getText();
    }

    this.clickMethod=function(){
        this.button.click();
    }
}

module.exports=indexFunction
```

when I run this example I got this error

```
[![MacBook-Pro:example naveenkumar$ protractor conf.js
Using ChromeDriver directly...
\[launcher\] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
\[launcher\] Error: Error: Cannot find module '/indexFunction'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:326:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:277:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/naveenkumar/Desktop/example/example_spec.js:2:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:398:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:405:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:][1]][1]
```

[image]

**Update**

```
r: Error: Cannot find module '/index.spec'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:326:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:277:25)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `example.spec.js` it should be:

```
var indexFunction = require('./index.spec');
```

Comment: stll same issue... can we include any module for require?